# how to download webgl unity game to use offline

Tags: webgl, wget, unity-webgl

I want to download some game(for using offline and for keep it in archive) which built with Unity in WebGL format. I tried downloading it with wget and HTTrack,but when I running it on local web server I  only get errors like this: "An error occurred running Unity content".
In Chrome Developer Console I see this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) UnityLoader.js:3 Invoking error handler due to Script error. index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (UnityLoader.js:4) index.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Is it possible to download Unity WebGL game? If yes, how?
I worried that if this is not possible, that can lead to losing a lot of content,because of sites sometimes went down.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.